# is it possible to allow utf-8 encoding for one repository and gbk encoding for another?

Tags: git, web, encoding

environment:
SUSE Linux enterprise server 11 sp1
git version 1.6.0.2
gitoite for access control
git web run on apache 

i have two repositories .  in repo a , it's encoding
 is gbk , while repo b is utf-8.

then if repo a has chinese code, chinese character
 will be messy code when viewed by git web

but chinese code in repo b will show correctly.

so  i want to ask if it is possible to for git web to recognize
 different encoding for different repositories . 
and can show chinese code

Answer (score 0):

(I don't possess the definitive knowledge on the subject; I'll just summarize what I know about encodings in Git.)

There are two kinds of objects, the contents of which is subject to be *interpreted* as being in a certain encoding:

- Commits (commit messages are the main part of this).
- BLOBs — the contents of files.

With regard to commits, Git has three [configuration](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) knobs to control encoding:

- `i18n.commitEncoding`: when set (to the name of an encoding), tells Git to put a special header into a commit object which specifies the encoding of the commit message.

  Conversely, tool which read such a commit object might parse out this header and use the knowledge of the commit's encoding to properly recode the commit contents into their *native* representation.
- `i18n.logOutputEncoding` might be used to change Git's idea about the encoding of the user's terminal, when writing there the results of running the `git log` command.
- `gui.encoding`: when set, makes the standard Git GUI tools (`gitk` and `git gui`) assume *all* the files in the repository are encoded in the specified encoding.  This allows these tools to properly re-encode the contents of files to their native encoding.

  The Git tools can be hinted at the native encoding of files in the repository on a *per-file basis* — using the `encoding` parameters in the [`.gitattributes` file](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

So, what you can try to do about configuring `gitweb`…  It all depends on whether this tool honors the configuration knobs described above.

For a start, I would try to properly set the `gui.encoding` in your repository (note: in the repository which is accessed by `gitweb`).

If you're using GBK in your commit messages, you *have* to have an appropriate encoding header in these commit objects, otherwise it's not gonna work, I reckon.  If you don't have them, consider doing a test [history rewriting](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) of your repository.  This would require doing some research.

You might also look at tweaking your web server configuration to force the CGI tools it runs, including `gitweb`, to see a GBK-enabled locale in their environment — this *might* make `gitweb` just "pass-through" the contents of your files when showing them. I'm not sure it's gonna work but at least you could try.